# Gnome defaults to wayland; how can I go to back to X11?

Tags: arch-linux, x11, gnome, wayland

I updated Gnome to the newest version and I realized that wayland has been installed as the default window manager. I have many problems with it, so how do I go to back to X11?

I'm using Arch.

//EDIT

Problem solved. I just delete old x11 config and create new one :)

`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` returns X11 :)

Comment: You know these days you don't need a configuration file at all

Answer (score 20):

From an arch wiki Use Xorg backend

> The Wayland backend is used by default and the Xorg backend is used
>   only if the Wayland backend cannot be started. As the Wayland backend
>   has been reported to cause problems for some users, use of the Xorg
>   backend may be necessary.

To use the Xorg backend by default, edit the

```
 /etc/gdm/custom.conf file and uncomment the following line:

#WaylandEnable=false
```

I hope it is current.

Comment: Isn't that just forcing to use X11 for GDM and not the user session?

Comment: I'm tired that and my GUI didn't run so I was force to back to comment that line

Comment: This is the correct solution. However, GDM runs as a service, so you will need to either `sudo systemctl restart gdm` or reboot to ensure this takes effect.

Comment: In my debian 10 Is explicitly stated under the file : /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf

Comment: On my Ubuntu 22.04, the file is /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Answer (score 1):

In gdm, you should have a little gear bellow the field you are entering your password. There you should be able to select the X11 session

Comment: Yes Im able to choose beetwen Xorg and Wayland session problem is when Im choosing Xorg I have black mirror for 1-2 sec and then again back to field when you are entering your password

Answer (score -1):

Here is output of:

journalctl -e -u gdm

```
sty 10 11:01:40 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10757 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:40 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10776 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:40 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process 10761 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:40 RarezPC gdm[348]: Unable to kill session worker process
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10816 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process 10796 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Unable to kill session worker process
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10835 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process 10821 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Unable to kill session worker process
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10854 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10854 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10873 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process 10858 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Unable to kill session worker process
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10892 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10892 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: GdmLaunchEnvironment: Unknown user gdm
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: GLib-GObject: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process -10925 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Child process 10897 was already dead.
sty 10 11:01:41 RarezPC gdm[348]: Unable to kill session worker process
sty 10 11:02:12 RarezPC systemd[1]: Stopping GNOME Display Manager...
sty 10 11:02:13 RarezPC systemd[1]: Stopped GNOME Display Manager.
```

Comment: Now I have another problem :/ Failed to contact accountsservice, AccountsService: Failed to create accounts proxy: